# Sum of nonzero squares modulo p

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

It is easy to prove that for prime $p$ every element of $\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$ can be written as the sum of two squares. An elementary proof is given here: [Sum of two squares modulo p](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891861/sum-of-two-squares-modulo-p)

How can we show that, provided further $p \geq 7$, any nonzero element of $\mathbb{Z}/ p \mathbb{Z}$ is the sum of two nonzero squares? I don't see how we could extend the counting argument used in the linked post to this case. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that this *should* be true? That is, is it an exercise from a book or something?

Comment: It's an exercise from a course I'm taking, so it should be true. Do you have a counterexample?

Comment: No, I don't. Just making sure of not trying to prove a false statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapting [Mikhail Ivanov's argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1690525/11619) to a slightly different but AFAICT equivalent question to fit here. Some of the elements appeared also in my answer to that question.

---

Every non-zero element of $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ is either a square or a non-square
If $a=b^2$ is a non-zero square, then, as $p>5$ we have
$$
a=b^2=(3b/5)^2+(4b/5)^2
$$
as a sum of two non-zero squares.

On the other hand, if $a$ is a non-zero non-square then $ab^2$ is a non-zero non-square for any $b\neq0$. Furthermore, we get all the non-squares in this way. If $a=x^2+y^2$ with $xy\neq0$, then $ab^2=(bx)^2+(by)^2$, so it suffices to show that we can write at least one of the non-squares as a sum of two non-zero squares. Let's pretend for one time's sake that $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ has an "order", so $0<1<2<\ldots<p-1$. Let $a$ be the smallest non-square in this order. Clearly $a>1$. It follows that $a-1=b^2$ is a square, where $b\neq0$. This implies that $a=1+b^2$ is a sum of two non-zero squares. Therefore so are all the other non-squares.

Comment: Thanks, that's great

Comment: How can we guarantee that division by 5 holds? For example, let p = 7, b = 2. Then there is no number n such that 5n = 6.

Comment: @SamuelBarkes In $\Bbb{Z}/7\Bbb{Z}$ we have $5\cdot4=6$.  Because $5\cdot3=1$ in that field, we have $x/5=3x$ for all $x$. In your example case $6/5=3\cdot6=4$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's prove that $1$ is the sum of two nonzero squares.

Think about the geometry of the plane. Any non-vertical line through
$(1,0)$ will meet the unit circle in another point. This argument
works over $k=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ too. The "non-vertical" lines through
$(1,0)$ are $y=m(x-1)$, and each meets the unit circle in the
further point $((m^2-1)/(m^2+1),2m/(m^2+1))$, as long as $m^2\ne-1$.
These coordinates are nonzero iff $m\notin\{0,1,-1\}$. There are
at most five "bad" values of $m$, so if $p>5$, then $1$ is the sum of
two non-zero squares in $k$.

By scaling, each non-zero square is the sum of
two non-zero squares in $k$. Of course, if $b$ is not a square, it is still the sum of two squares, and they are both nonzero.

Comment: "This argument works over $k=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ too". Why? If fact, we have $3^2+3^2\equiv 4^2+6^2\equiv 1\pmod{17}$. That is, for $p=17$, the line intersects the circle at three points.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown , I have been used your answer to complete my proof.

Comment: @ajotatxe Really, there is no line in the affine plane $k^2$ that meets the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ in three distinct points.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, since a crucial part is not proved.

> **Conjecture**: Given an odd prime $p$, the cardinal of the set $$A_p=\{(x,y):0\le x\le(p-1)/2,\, 0\le y\le(p-1)/2,\, x^2+y^2\equiv 1\!\!\!\!\!\mod p\}$$ is
>   $$\begin{cases}(p+3)/4\text{ if } p\equiv 1\pmod 4\\(p+5)/4\text{ if
>  }p\equiv 3\pmod 4\end{cases}$$

This conjecture is based in evidence for odd primes less than $2000$, that I have tried using a program.

Now, assuming this conjecture, let's prove the statement. Take $a\in\Bbb Z_p^\times$ and suppose that $a$ is not the sum of two nonzero squares. Since $a$ is the sum of two squares, we see that $a$ must be a square itself, say $a=b^2$.

The conjecture implies that the number of elements in $A_p$ is at least $3$ for $p\ge 7$. Then, $A_p$ contains an element other than $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. This shows that $1$ is the sum of two nonzero squares. That is,
$$x^2+y^2\equiv 1\pmod p$$
And, now, multiplying by $b^2$ (which is not $0$), we get
$$(bx)^2+(by)^2\equiv a\pmod p$$

Comment: I'm fairly sure that in Ireland & Rosen the formula for the solutions of $x^2+y^2=1$ is proven. It gives $|A_p'|=p-\left(\dfrac{-1}p\right)$, where   $A_p'$ is the set of solutions $(x,y)$ with the bounds $0\le x,y\le p-1$. I think that this suffices for your argument. I did something similar [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1690500/11619).

Answer (score 0):

**Lemma**: 
Let $7 \leq p$ be a prime number; 
then $1$ can be written as the sum of two non-zero squares.
**Proof**: 
See the [answer of Lord Shark the Unknown to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2410920/sum-of-nonzero-squares-modulo-p/2410928#2410928).

---

---

Let $a \in \left(\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{\mathbb{pZ}}\right)^*$ be arbitrary; 
let's define the sets $A_a$ and $B$ as follows:

$$ 
B:= 
\Bigg{\{} 
x^2 : x \in \dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{\mathbb{pZ}}
\Bigg{\}} 
;
\\ 
A_a:= 
a-B= 
\Bigg{\{} 
a-x^2 : x \in \dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{\mathbb{pZ}}
\Bigg{\}} 
;
$$

notice that, each of the above sets has exactly $\dfrac{p+1}{2}$ elements.

---

**Claim**: $B \cap A_a \neq \phi$, 
in other words there is $t \in \dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{\mathbb{pZ}} $ 
such that $t^2 \in B$ and $t^2 \in A_a$.
**Prood**: Suppose on contrary $B \cap A_a = \phi$; 
so we can conclude that: 
$\Big{|}B \cup A_a \Big{|} = \Big{|} B \Big{|} + \Big{|} A_a \Big{|}$;
on the other hand we know 
$B \cup A_a  \subseteq \dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{\mathbb{pZ}}$, 
so we can conclude that:

$$ 
p+1 
= 
\dfrac{p+1}{2} + \dfrac{p+1}{2} 
= 
\Big{|} B \Big{|} + \Big{|} A_a \Big{|} 
= 
\Big{|} B \cup A_a \Big{|} 
\leq 
\Big{|} \dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{\mathbb{pZ}} \Big{|} 
= 
p 
; 
$$

which is an obvious contradiction.

---

---

**Remark** : 
Let $7 \leq p$ be a prime number, 
then every nonzero element 
$a \in \left(\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{\mathbb{pZ}}\right)^*$ 
can be written as the sum of two non-zero squares.
**Proof** : 
By the above claim, 
there is $x \in \dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{\mathbb{pZ}} $ 
such that $x^2 \in A_a$,
so there is $y \in \dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{\mathbb{pZ}} $ such that $x^2=a-y^2$; 
which proves the remark.

---

**Proof of the original problem**:

By the previous remark every 
$a \in \left(\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{\mathbb{pZ}}\right)^*$ 
can be written in the form $x^2+y^2$; 
notice that $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$, so we have the following cases:

- $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$; in this case there is nothing left to prove. 
  $\checkmark$
- $x \neq 0$ and $y = 0$ . 
  By the lemma, $1$ can be written in the form $a^2+b^2$; 
  where both of $c, d$ are non-zero, only notice that: 
  $$ 
  a 
  \overset{p}{\equiv} 
  1 \cdot a 
  \overset{p}{\equiv} 
  (c^2+d^2) (x^2+0^2) 
  \overset{p}{\equiv} 
  (cx)^2+(dx)^2 
  . 
  $$
- $x = 0$ and $y \neq 0$ . 
  By the lemma, $1$ can be written in the form $a^2+b^2$; 
  where both of $c, d$ are non-zero, only notice that: 
  $$ 
  a 
  \overset{p}{\equiv} 
  1 \cdot a 
  \overset{p}{\equiv} 
  (c^2+d^2) (0^2+y^2) 
  \overset{p}{\equiv} 
  (cy)^2+(dy)^2 
  . 
  $$

Comment: How do we know that $x, y$ are nonzero?

Comment: We've specified that $p \geq 7$, so the first doesn't apply, and for the second $4 \equiv 1^2 + 4^2 (\mathrm{ mod } 13)$.

Comment: Given the hypothesis in the question (i.e. $p \geq 7$), can we show that any nonzero element is the sum of two nonzero squares?

Comment: $5 = 1^2 + 2^2$ though?

Comment: @Rafa , Dear Rafa, I have been used; ***the other answer to this question*** ; as a lemma, to complete my proof. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathbf F_p :=\mathbf Z /p\mathbf Z$ is a field, it seems adequate to heartily use the theory of finite fields, more specifically the central result that an extension $\mathbf F_q /\mathbf F_p$, with $q=p^n$, is Galois with cyclic group of order $n$ generated by the Frobenius automorphism $\phi: x \to x^p$. It follows easily that the norm map $N:\mathbf F_q^{*} \to \mathbf F_p^{*}$ is surjective. For later use, I include a *quick proof* : by Hilbert's 90, $x\in KerN$ iff $x$ is of the form $\phi(z)/z = z^{p-1}$; in particular, since $\mathbf F_q^{*}$ is cyclic, $KerN$ has order $(q-1)/(p-1)$, hence $ImN$ has order $p-1$, i.e. $N$ is surjective.

Apply this for $n=2$ : if $p\neq 2$, then $\mathbf F_{p^2} = \mathbf F_p (\sqrt d)$ where $d$ is the class of a *non* quadratic residue mod $p$, hence every $x\in \mathbf F_p^{*}$ can be written $x=a^2 -db^2$ = a sum of two squares. But one of these squares could still be zero, so it remains to prove that every element of $(\mathbf F_p^{*})^2$ is a sum of two nonzero squares, or equivalently that $1=x^2+y^2, xy\neq0$. The latter property has been shown in the answers given by @Jyrki Lahtonen and @Lord Shark the Unknown. Although it's not necessary to give all the solutions $(x, y)$, let's provide a parametrization analogous to that of the pythagorean triples ((3, 4, 5) is the "first" such triple). Put $1=a^2-db^2$= a norm from $\mathbf F_p (\sqrt d)$ with $d$ as above. The same argument using Hilbert's 90 will give $a+b\sqrt d= \phi(z)/z$, and writing $z=e+f\sqrt d$, we'll get $a=(e^2+df^2)/(e^2-df^2)$ and $y=-2ef/(e^2-df^2)$ . For example, if $d=-1$, we recover $(\frac 35)^2 + (\frac 45)^2 =1$ by taking $e=2, f=-1$.