# Primes dividing sums of squares but not dividing any of summands

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, sums-of-squares

I am inexperienced when it comes to number theory (even elementary one) so do not have an idea at this moment on how to solve this one.

Let us go through some examples.

For $k=2$ we can have prime that divides $n_1^2 + n_2^2$ but that does not divide neither $n_1$ nor $n_2$. Take $n_1=3$ and $n_2=5$. That prime here is $p=17$.

For $k=3$ we can take as an example $n_1=3$ and $n_2=5$ and $n_3=7$. Then the prime is $p=83$.

For $k=4$ we can give an example $n_1=n_2=3$ and $n_3=n_4=5$. Then the prime is $p=17$.

We will not allow that our prime $p$ be equal to $2$ so we will search for counterexamples that have $p\neq 2$.

Question is:

> Is it true that for every $k \in \mathbb N \setminus \{1\}$ there exist natural numbers $w_1,w_2,...w_k$ (all different from $1$) such that there is a prime $p \neq 2$ that divides $\sum_{i=1}^k w_i^2$ but does not divide any of the numbers $w_1,w_2,...w_k$?

I am not sure in my fluency of English, so when I say that "$p$ does not divide any of the numbers $w_1,w_2,...w_k$" I mean that $p$ does not divide $w_1$ and $p$ does not divide $w_2$ and ... and $p$ does not divide $w_k$.

Comment: This seems obvious. Have you tried induction on $k$?

Comment: @Crostul No, I tend to avoid induction-based proofs, if possible.

Comment: For when $k$ is not a power of $2$, take $w_i=1~\forall~1\leq i\leq k$ and $p$ an odd prime divisor of $k$.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I will edit to avoid trivial counterexamples.

Comment: If all  $w_i = 1$ then any prime divisor of $k$ will do.

Comment: @EthanBolker I made an edit to avoid cuh a family of counterexamples, we are not interested in that, right?

Comment: @EthanBolker, That doesn't work when $k$ is a power of $2$ though.

Comment: To make it even more difficult : What if we further demand that the $w's$ are pairwise distinct ?

Comment: @Peter I was thinking about some variants of that, not exactly of that but of something approximately similar.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin The linked question I asekd received a beautiful answer!

Answer (score 3):

We have $$131=3^2+4^2+5^2+9^2=5^2+5^2+9^2$$ If $k\ne 5$ and $k>2$, there are non-negative integers $a$ and $b$ wirh $3a+4b=k$ Use the summands of the first represenation $b$ times and the summands of the second representaition $a$ times.

Moreover, $131|7^2+9^2+4^2+4^2+10^2$ , so the cases $k=5$ is solved as well.

Comment: But does such representation allow number $1$? I am sure that it is.

Comment: 17=4^2+1^2? Or I did not understand your answer.

Comment: Yes, this would be an allowed representation and $17$ does neither divide $1$ nor $4$

Comment: But I do not allow that summands take value 1, I made an edit to avoid repetitions of 1 and trivial counterexamples.

Comment: I made an edit a little bit before this answer.

Comment: But Peter, all the $w_i$ must be different than 1.

Comment: Then, my method doesn't work. Sorry, didn't notice that you demand that.. But the prime is arbitary, yes ?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn´t work but it is a nice idea. I conceived this question after some thinking about sums of squares and although trivial I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Yes, p does not need to be fixed through all counterexamples of this conjecture.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin Edited my answer.

Comment: What if $\sum w_i^2$ is divisible by 3? Or 5.

Answer (score 2):

We will prove a more stronger claim

**Question(I)**: 
Suppose that the natural number $k \geq 3$ 
and a prime number $p \geq 7$ are given; then there exist natural numbers $w_1,w_2,...w_k$ (all different from $1$) such that $p$ divides $\sum_{i=1}^k w_i^2$ but does not divide any of the numbers $w_1,w_2,...w_k$?

Before proving this; we will prove another problem:
**Question(I)**: 
Suppose that the natural number $k \geq 3$ 
and a prime number $p \geq 7$ are given; then there exist natural numbers $w_1, w_2, ..., w_k$ such that $p$ divides $\sum_{i=1}^k w_i^2$ but does not divide any of the numbers $w_1,w_2,...w_k$?

---

---

**Lemma**: 
Given a prime number $p \geq 7$ and any integer $a$ such that $p \nmid a$.
Then there are natural numbers $n, m$ such that:

$$p \mid n^2+m^2-a; \qquad \qquad p\nmid n; \qquad \qquad p \nmid m. $$ 
**Proof**: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2410920/sum-of-nonzero-squares-modulo-p/2410939#2410939).

---

Proof of question(II):

- If $p\nmid k-2$
  let $w_1=w_2=...=w_{k-2}=1$; and let $a=-\sum_{i=1}^{k-2}w_i^2$;
  now by the above lemma there are natural numbers $n, m$ such that $p\mid n^2+m^2-a$;
  now let $w_{k-1}=n$ and $w_{k}=m$; so we have done!
- If $p\nmid k+1$
  let $w_1=w_2=...=w_{k-3}=1$, $w_{k-2}=2$; and let $a=-\sum_{i=1}^{k-2}w_i^2$;
  now by the above lemma there are natural numbers $n, m$ such that $p\mid n^2+m^2-a$;
  now let $w_{k-1}=n$ and $w_{k}=m$; so we have done!

---

By considering the argument described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2452812/can-we-prove-a-stronger-claim/2452837#2452837) 
question(I) follows immediately from question(II).

---

At the end for the case $k=2$, you can choose $p \overset{4}{\equiv}1$ arbitrary;
 and again there exist integers $m, n$ such that: 
$$p \mid n^2+m^2; \qquad \qquad p\nmid n; \qquad \qquad p \nmid m. $$